# How to test spring Boot rest controllers with MockMvc by skipping repository classes?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to create Test class for Controller as below:
Please note that we have created library for all repositories&domains (Using Spring DATA JPA) and added the dependency in actual application where UserController resides.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = UserController.class, secure = false)
public class UserControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void testGetUsers() throws Exception {
        when(userService.getAllUser()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Organization>());
        mvc.perform(get("/users")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

When I tried to run this class, I got exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4d41ba0f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

How to test spring Boot rest controllers with MockMvc by skipping repository classes ?

Comment: I understood incorrectly your question. I will delete my question. You are having some sort of problem on the entity manager configuration. Do you have the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` on your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes. the problem is when I ran specific test class its scanning all the components mentioned in the @SpringBootApplication. How to overcome that one ?

Comment: Did you try some `@MockBean` for entityManagerFactory???. Or run test with `debug=true` property, find and disable unnecessary auto-configuration beans -  for example `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you didn't provide other beans, which are `@Autowired` in your `UserController` class. In `@WebMvcTest` beans don't undergo standard spring process of creation.

To quickly fix this, just provide other beans to tour test class annotated with `@MockBean`

Example controller class:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    AnotherSillyBean anotherSillyBean;

    ...
}
```

Example test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = UserController.class, secure = false)
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @MockBean
    AnotherSillyBean anotherSillyBean;

    ...
}
```